# How can I sign using .pfx certificate in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, pfx

I have a .pfx certificate file on my computer. I want to sign message with its private key, and then check the signature. And I need to get the information about the sertificate the message was signed with from that message.

How can I do it using it in Flutter?